# Is it valid to manipulate the unit of time for Poisson distributed counts?

Tags: poisson-distribution, simulation, count-data

If I have discrete count data measured in minutes (60/minute) that does not fit the Poisson distribution (variance >> mean), is it valid to increase the granularity of that data to seconds if it evens out the variance and mean?

If so, are there any limits to the amount of scaling transformations you can apply to count data to get it to fit Poisson? Or is it valid to shrink the time-scale I am looking at for the process until the assumption of mean ~= var is met?

Comment: It rather depends on how many observations you have; if this is very small, spitting the data up to have sixty times as many may be helpful anyway (and the ratio between variance and mean can vary a lot with a small number of samples from the Poisson distribution), but if not, then you are deluding yourself: if the data does not come from a Poisson distribution then why pretend it does?